# Blender closes when I right click

Tags: selection-tools

I was working on this project, and out of the blue, when I right click, Blender crashes. It only happens in this project, and I'll attach the project.I'm fairly new to Blender. This started occurring after a test render

https://www.dropbox.com/s/w6lmq3k2ywhylg5/blender%20project.blend?dl=0

Comment: I'm just going to start a new project

Comment: It's because you set the subdivision level of the `NurbsPath` object to 6. Never set it that high

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **Outliner** to select the object that causes this problem.

And avoid subdividing objects more than 4 times as this may be too much for your hardware.

Almost three million faces for such simple objects is a bit of an exaggeration, most likely it's beyond the limit of what your computer can handle.

[image]